# What is the fully qualified path of the Neo4j data directory on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: neo4j

I can't find the data directory for my Neo4j Enterprise installation. I have looked at the config files and understand that it is in the data/graph.db file.

What is the default fully qualified path of the neo4j data directory?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The fully qualified path to the Neo4j 2.0M6 data directory on Ubuntu 12.04 is `'/var/lib/neo4j/data'`

The path is also shown at the bottom of the 'Database Information' panel in the Neo4j Browser.