# Where is the home-folder of a neo4j installation on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, ubuntu-14.04

I did google this, but I can only find the [data-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083966/what-is-the-fully-qualified-path-of-the-neo4j-data-directory-on-ubuntu-12-04).
Any help?

Answer (score 15):

Ah, seems like the binary folder is right next to the data-folder

> /var/lib/neo4j/bin